# windows 8/10 store app: SetPointerCapture not working at all?

Tags: windows-8

As I understood `CoreWindow::SetPointerCapture` should do the same as the good-old win32-Clipcursor. Actually I found that it does pretty much nothing.

Anybody got this running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SetPointerCapture captures the pointer.  Exact equivalent of the win32 SetCapture() function.  It is the basic OS function you'd need to, say, reliably generate a Click or MouseUp notification for a button or ensure a popup window like a context menu is closed when the user clicks outside of it.  You rarely have to call it yourself since most controls already take care of it by themselves.

Nothing to do with trapping the mouse into a box.  ClipCursor() only exists in win32 because they made a mistake 29 years ago at Windows v1.0, trivially defeated today by pressing Ctrl+Esc.  It was not carried forward into WinRT, you can't trap the user.

Comment: Oh my - thank you ! Didn't know there's actually a way NOT to capture mouse input. 

Ok, since the MouseDevice::mouseMoved event also seems to be faulty as hell (losing whole frames - and might even affect performance as of now) i just have to skip this for windows 8. Poor win8 customers.